# Задача на С#: В чем ошибка?

Tags: c#

Напишите функцию, вычисляющую длину отрезка по координатам его концов. С помощью этой функции напишите программу, вычисляющую периметр треугольника по координатам трех его вершин.
Формат ввода

На вход программе подается 6 целых чисел — координат x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3 вершин треугольника. Все числа по модулю не превосходят 30000.
Формат вывода

Выведите значение периметра этого треугольника с точностью до 6 знаков после десятичной точки.
Пример 1

Ввод
0 0 1 0 0 1

Вывод
3.4142135624

```
using System;

namespace zp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] t = Console.ReadLine().Split();
            int x1 = int.Parse(t[0]);
            int y1 = int.Parse(t[1]);
            int x2 = int.Parse(t[2]);
            int y2 = int.Parse(t[3]);
            int x3 = int.Parse(t[4]);
            int y3 = int.Parse(t[5]);
            double l = Math.Sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));
            l += Math.Sqrt((x1 - x3) * (x1 - x3) + (y1 - y3) * (y1 - y3));
            l += Math.Sqrt((x3 - x2) * (x3 - x2) + (y3 - y2) * (y3 - y2));
            Console.WriteLine("{0:f6}", l);
        }
    }
}
```

Решала на С#, не могу понять, что не так. Буду очень благодарна, если поможете переделать

Comment: Как по мне, так работает правильно `1+1+Sqrt(2)=3,41`

Comment: что выводить ваш код?

Comment: а в чем ошибка приведенный пример правильно работает и выдает правильный ответ?

Comment: Яндекс.Контест выводит ошибку

Comment: а какую ошибку, возможно оно не только целые числа тестирует, но и 1.5 например и т.д.

Comment: @ExplodingKitten `На вход программе подается 6 целых чисел`

Comment: У меня помимо ответа ниже еще одно не сходится `Вывод 3.4142135624` и `с точностью до 6 знаков после десятичной точки`. Я 10 знаков после точки насчитал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по заданию, вы про "напишите функцию" забыли.

Еще поправил запятую в выводе на точку.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] t = Console.ReadLine().Split();
        int x1 = int.Parse(t[0]);
        int y1 = int.Parse(t[1]);
        int x2 = int.Parse(t[2]);
        int y2 = int.Parse(t[3]);
        int x3 = int.Parse(t[4]);
        int y3 = int.Parse(t[5]);
        double l = LineLength(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        l += LineLength(x1, y1, x3, y3);
        l += LineLength(x3, y3, x2, y2);
        Console.WriteLine(l.ToString("F6", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }

    static double LineLength(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
    {
        return Math.Sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));
    }
}
```

Вывод

```
0 0 1 0 0 1
3.414214
```